Disabling Multi-View/stereoscopy in viewports
When using Multi-View to render many cameras—oddly exposed under "Stereoscopy"—how do I make it so that the viewports aren't showing red/blue? I'm not making a stereoscope, I'm just trying to batch render many cameras.
Before enabling Stereoscopy/Multi-View, Solid shading displays as desired:

Enabling Multi-View renders red/blue in every 3D viewport mode:



Open the Sidebar for each 3D Viewport you want to fix.
View ▸ Sidebar, or put the cursor over the viewport and press N
Click on the View tab on the right side of the sidebar.
In the Stereoscopy section, choose Views instead of 3D.


